# Installing Multicraft on EC2 Instance, phpMyAdmin will not load on browser

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I'm following the instructions located at [this page](https://www.vultr.com/docs/multicraft-minecraft-panel-on-centos-6).

I'm at step 3 where it says:

> You can now login to phpMyAdmin through either yourdomain.com/phpMyAdmin or yourserverIP/phpMyAdmin. Please note that phpMyAdmin is case sensitive.

I have tried going to `xx.xx.xx.xx/phpMyAdmin` and to `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin` to try to configure it, but the page does not load. I have configured the security groups as seen [in this screenshot.](https://gyazo.com/a519b79a412e0c88d3ed1823ed2f45e7)

All I get when I do `xx.xx.xx.xx/phpMyAdmin` all I get is:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> [IP Address] refused to connect.
>
> Search Google for phpMyAdmin
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm very stuck. I assume I can't continue without configuring the databases.

Comment: Can you access `xx.xx.xx.xx`?